# Vue.js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $set is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm fetching comments from the reddit API and trying to update an array with $set so it can update the view, but I get this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $set is not a function`

VM component:

```
export default {
  name: 'top-header',
  components: {
      Comment
  },
  data () {
    return {
      username: '',
      comments: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
      fetchData: function(username){
          var vm = this;
          this.$http.get(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${username}/comments.json?jsonp=`)
          .then(function(response){
              response.body.data.children.forEach(function(item, idx){
                  vm.comments.$set(idx, item); 
              });
          });
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set up a codepen to demonstrate the two possibilities: http://codepen.io/tuelsch/pen/YNOqYR?editors=1010

The $set method is only available on the component itself:

```
.then(function(response){
     // Overwrite comments array directly with new data
     vm.$set(vm, 'comments', response.body.data.children);
 });
```

or, since Vue.js sould be able to trace the push call on an array:

```
.then(function(response){
     // Clear any previous comments
     vm.comments = [];

     // Push new comments
     response.body.data.children.forEach(function(item){
         vm.comments.push(item); 
     });
 });
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set for the API reference.

Alternatively, you can use the global Vue.set method with the same parameters:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
// ...
Vue.set(vm, 'comments', response.body.data.children);
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set for the global API reference.

Comment: It's giving `ReferenceError: comments is not defined`

Comment: I did your edit in case, but it's still not updating the view. I'm doing a `v-for` to print them out, and it doesn't update.

Comment: Sorry, totally overlooked that comments is an array. I'd recommend the push version.